# How to allow special characters in JSON_VALUE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a VARCHAR column I use as JSON. In the column is the following data: `{"Key-Name": "A value."}`.

If I use JSON_VALUE to filter on this column with the query below I get the following error: "JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '-' is found at position 5.".

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE JSON_VALUE([Value], N'$.Key-Name') = 'A value'
```

How can I retrieve values with the JSON_VALUE function when keys have special characters in them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use double quotes to escape the key name:

```
SELECT *
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE JSON_VALUE([Value], N'$."Key-Name"') = 'A value'
```

Comment: For anyone who stumbles on this, the quotes will also handle situations where the JSON has `$` in the key name, too.