# Special character in JSON_VALUE in MSSQL 2017

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to extract an element from a json in a column.

However, the key of the element I am interested contains `%` (the exact name is: `Use%`).

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52057193/how-to-allow-special-characters-in-json-value), I tried to use double quotes, however, I still have the same problem:

```
JSON_VALUE(results, '$."Use%"') as value
```

> JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ''' is found
> at position 1.

```
  JSON_VALUE(results, '$.Use%') as value
```

> JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '%' is found
> at position 5.

How can I extract the value from my json string ?

The JSON is the following:

```
{'Filesystem': 'hdfs://nameservice1', 'Size': '67945349394432', 'Used': '22662944968704', 'Available': '41812184838144', 'Use%': '33%'}
```

Comment: Show us what the JSON data you actually have is.

Comment: Your JSON isn't valid, it should be using double quotes, not single quotes. You'll need to `REPLACE` those single quotes (`'`) with double quotes (`"`). Once you do that, your first attempt works fine.

Comment: @Larnu Indeed, seems like I misread the first error... Thanks. If you write an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Larnu is correct, see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/VYlPcHEf) for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't your attempt, it's your JSON; it isn't valid JSON. JSON uses double quotes (`"`) for delimit identifing not single quotes (`'`). For the example we have, simply `REPLACE`ing the single quotes with double quotes fixes the problem:

```sql
DECLARE @YourJSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'{''Filesystem'': ''hdfs://nameservice1'', ''Size'': ''67945349394432'', ''Used'': ''22662944968704'', ''Available'': ''41812184838144'', ''Use%'': ''33%''}';

SELECT JSON_VALUE(REPLACE(@YourJSON, '''', '"'), '$."Use%"') AS value;
```

Of course, I strongly suggest you investigate how you are creating JSON which uses single quotes, rather than double quotes, and fix both your existing data and process that creates it.